# Can not get the value from input Livewire?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have this form :

```
<div class="coupon d-flex align-items-center">

  <input wire.model="coupon" type="text" class="input-text">

  <button wire:click="applyCoupon" class="ml-3">@lang('site.apply_coupon')</button>

</div>
```

My Component:

```
class CouponCart extends Component
{
  public $coupon;

  public function applyCoupon(){
      dd($this->coupon);
  }

  public function render()
  {
     return view('livewire.user.coupon-cart');
  }
}
```

Why I always get null value when I click button ? even I fill the input!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it's [`wire:model`](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/properties#data-binding) instead of `wire.model`.

You probably made a typo and added a `.` instead.